# Make an alert with javascript if two numbers are equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote this code to make that when I click the button the alert says if the random numbers are equal or not. The 2 random numbers have to be between 1 and 6 and not to be decimal numbers.
I set this in javascript but it isn't working...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Numeri Casuali</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function casuali() {
      var a, b;
      var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      if (a == b) {
        alert("Equals")
      } else {
        alert("Not Equals")
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick=”casuali()”>Clicca qui</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why `else if()` and not just `else`?

Comment: Sorry, it's a little mistake.

Comment: Your correction is still faulty. Why the `()` ?

Comment: Look at the developer console. There will be errors

Comment: The error is due to using `”` instead of `"`. If you remove that, and keep the `int` to `var` change, this all works. I am closing as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is clearly this

`onclick=”casuali()”`

need to be `onclick="casuali()"`

Answer (score 2):

Your variable declaration is wrong, there's no `int` in javascript like you might know from java or other typed languages. In javascript, we use `var`, `let` or `const`. [js is loosely typed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures).

```
int a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
int b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

change that to

```
var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

and remove the `var a,b;`, or simply use

```
a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

also it's `else` not `else ()`

Complete working code:

```
function casuali() {
    var a, b;
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if (a == b) {
        console.log("Equals")
    } else {
        console.log("Not Equals")
    }
}
```

Comment: I need them not to be a decimal number

Comment: They wont be, because you use `floor`. But be aware that the number datatype is always a float in JavaScript.

Comment: @trincot and how can I write the code to make not decimal numbers?

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi Javascript is an **untyped language**!

Comment: a and b can be everything you assign to it, there is no specified type for a variable in js. @NiccolòGuidi

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi `Math.random() * 6` is decimal but `Math.floor` return a non(decimal number!

Comment: It doesn't send me the alert... also with the new code

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues:
1- remove int from the following code:

```js
int a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
int b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

2- remove if() from the following:

```js
} else if() { 
alert("Not Equals")
}
```

So the correct code is:

```js
function casuali(){
var a,b;
 a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
 b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
if (a==b) {
alert("Equals")
} else  { 
alert("Not Equals")
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some typo errors in your JavaScript codes.

Here's the correct version:

```
function casuali(){ 
   var a,b;

   a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
   b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

    if (a==b) { 
        alert("Equals");
     } else { 
         alert("Not Equals");
     }
 }
```